# Keep similar parts of multiple strings, remove parts that are different in python

Tags: python, string

## Problem

I'm trying to parse through historical email subject lines. Unfortunately, the subject lines have dynamic fields, and the dynamic fields are often in different places:

### Email A:

- Heather, get 45 Points at Joey's Sandwich Shop!
- Justin, get 45 Points at Joey's Sandwich Shop!

### Email B:

- Welcome to the Program, Kelvin!
- Welcome to the Program, Joshua!

Is there a way to get the string from each email that is similar across every subject line?

## Ideal results

### Email A:

- [Name], get 45 Points at Joey's Sandwich Shop!

### Email B:

- Welcome to the Program, [Name]!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know exactly what will be after something you search or before the thing you search?
(known str) (unknown str)?

Comment: Hi Peter,

I believe so. The string will be identical other than the dynamic name field. Some strings won't have any dynamic fields and won't require any additional work.